# How to map my existing domain to Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I currently have a simple node webapp on a VPS, and like to run it on GCP instead.

This is a hobby project, therefore I am trying to prevent any cost and will try to remain within the free tier. I also want to prevent vendor lock in as much as possible.

I'm brand new to GCP and docker (I basically learnt docker and created this infrastructure at home in the last week). And the GCP possibilities and documentation are vast, and a bit overwhelming at times. But as I understand it, I have three options:

1. Cloud DNS ($1/zone/mo)
2. Using a Cloud Run Domain mapping
3. Using a "global external Application load balancer"

Option 1 is paid; not expensive, but there seems to be an options 2 and 3, which are described here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains. Option 2 still seems to be experimental and not generally available yet. I had hopes that option 3 allowed me to run a reverse proxy/load balancer as a Cloud Run Docker, but I am more and more starting to think this is not going to be possible.

This is my intended architecture. The six black bordered boxes are the required docker containers for this project, which I intend to run on Cloud Run.

[image: architecture]

- Any idea how I can link my own domain to it?
- Even if I cannot link a domain to my reverse proxy docker, can I even run a reverse proxy using Cloud Run?

Comment: All methods require a DNS server. #1 by itself you cannot use a DNS server to point to Cloud Run as the GFE must also be configured to recognize the hostname. #2 is the standard method of mapping a domain hostname to Cloud Run. #3 will also work but is more expensive (requires a load balancer) but does not require method #2. My recommendation is to configure something and then come back when you have a problem. You have a lot to learn about DNS and Cloud Run.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the GFE direction. I incorrectly thought this was a simple question, but I now see that there's much more to it.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki so others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @John Hanley:

> All methods require a DNS server. #1 by itself you cannot use a DNS server to point to Cloud Run as the GFE must also be configured to recognize the hostname. #2 is the standard method of mapping a domain hostname to Cloud Run. #3 will also work but is more expensive (requires a load balancer) but does not require method #2. My recommendation is to configure something and then come back when you have a problem. You have a lot to learn about DNS and Cloud Run.